# rvm + rails3 + gmaps4rails - acts_as_gmappable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am a noob with ruby rails and all. Sorry if my question is dumb.

I set up a environment with rvm (as a user) running ruby 1.8.7-p334. I have created a gemset for my "app" and now I would like to show a map of an address on the page. 
I've been looking around and found gmaps4rails.
I've add "gem 'gmaps4rails' "to my Gemfile & bundle install

I modified my model (added the required columns and rake db:migrate) and acts_as_gmappable and I get 
 `` undefined local variable or method `acts_as_gmappable' `` 
If I add require 'gmaps4rails' I get a 
 `no such file to load -- gmaps4rails`

Any ideas folks ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear it's my fault:

after hours fighting with pow: http://pow.cx/

I ended up making it work adding a `.rvmrc` file which sets the ruby version to `ree` and I forgot to add this file to my gitignore...

Well, should be ok in 0.8.3, let me know!

Comment: Good news, hopefuly you told it ;)

Comment: May I ask another question though?
I don't see the map on the web page, but some space is left blank for it. WEBrick output give me this when I try to access it:

Started GET "/stylesheets/gmaps4rails.css" for 192.168.0.9 at Wed May 04 18:54:23 +0200 2011
Started GET "/javascripts/gmaps4rails.js" for 192.168.0.9 at Wed May 04 18:54:23 +0200 2011

Do I need to define a route or something else ? 
Thanks again.

Comment: In development mode these files should be found, weird... You could copy/paste the js and css of the gem in you app.