# undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_gmappable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-snow-leopard, gmaps4rails

I attempted to install the gmaps4rails gem.

I added `gem 'gmaps4rails'` to my Gemfile, and ran `'bundle install`. It said that my bundle installed successfully. I can find `"Using gmaps4rails (0.8.8)"` with `'gem list'`. I added the specified columns to my users table with `rake db:migrate` and added `acts_as_gmappable` and the `gmaps4rails_address` method to my `User` model.

Visiting pages that involve the user model gives me `"undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_gmappable'"`error.

Is there something that I am missing?

For greater context, the code I am using is from the Rails 3 Tutorial.

OS X 10.6.6
ruby 1.8.7
rails 3.0.7
passenger 3.0.7

Comment: you should be running `bundle`, then `bundle install`.  are you using rvm?

Comment: Could you post the rest of the relevant code, such as your user.rb file?

Comment: did you restart the server after installing the gem?

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. It looks like restarting the server is what I was missing.

Comment: @ramc: I guess you should post your answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Restarting the server should resolve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue : undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_gmappable'

I just restarted the server and it error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Mongoid and had the same trouble.

In which case, make sure your model includes:

```
include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable

acts_as_gmappable :position => :location

field :gmaps, :type => Boolean
field :location, :type => Array

def gmaps4rails_address
  #describe how to retrieve the address from your model, if you use directly a db column, you can dry your code, see wiki
 "#{self.address}, #{self.city}, #{self.country}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be helpful (similar issue):

[rvm + rails3 + gmaps4rails - acts_as_gmappable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902452/rvm-rails3-gmaps4rails-acts-as-gmappable)